# DigitalOcean's object storage, Spaces, is randomly slow on retrieving small files

Tags: digital-ocean

We switched from a custom block storage solution to DigitalOcean's object storage and I'm kind of disappointed in the speed.

Is there anyway we could retrieve objects asynchronously? Also some objects that are around 50 KB can take from 57 ms to 3 seconds... Is this normal for object storage solutions or is this just an issue with DigitalOcean?

[image]

---

## Update from DigitalOcean:

After battling with support for the past week, I finally got an acceptable response:

> "Our Spaces team are aware of some possible performance bottlenecks and are working on addressing those." 
>   *- Mike G., Platform Support Advocate*

I did notice, a day after I submitted a support request (2017-12-18 ), the average speed was 0.74 seconds (with an avg. file size of 78.6 KB) before the [NYC3 storage went down](https://status.digitalocean.com/incidents/1fn0d47xfpy5). Now it's at 0.42 seconds with an avg. file size of 88.48 KB, tested on 2017-12-20.

Comment: It's faster to load one larger image than lots of smaller images with the same overall size due to the added time of initiating and closing a connection for each one. That's why sprite sheets are often used for this purpose. Is this something you could do?

Comment: They are product images, so this would not be a viable option. Thank you for the suggestion. :)

Comment: Your best bet would probably be to go to Digital Ocean support and ask them about this!

Comment: I did a few days ago, waiting for a response. I will  be sure to update this once I do get one.

Comment: See question and answers directly at: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/do-spaces-request-timing-is-slow-basic-images-load-slowly-poor-performance

Answer (score 5):

1) Object storage isn't designed to handle the workload you're intended to use it for. Making a long story short: Hash-based K/V seeks won't ever reach performance of a block device "immediate" seeks thru LBA addressing.

https://cloudstore.interoute.com/knowledge-centre/library/object-storage-use-cases

2) Digital Ocean is just @#$^E%^# storage system! Drop it like it's hot, and replace it with COTS hardware combined with Ceph.

http://ceph.com/ceph-storage/object-storage/

Comment: Just learned that Digital Ocean is using Ceph as their backend: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/pages/spaces_update?utm_medium=email&utm_source=newsletter&utm_campaign=ProductBroadcast082018

Comment: Badly configured Ceph or GlusterFS won’t perform well. You don’t want to rely on somebody else’s installation you can do nothing to fix.

Answer (score 0):

randomly slow, good luck troubleshooting object storage performance - Digital ocean could be throttling you, the object storage public endpoint is ...public. It could also depend on your out going proxy server or ISP, anyway I would not expect it to be anything like as performant as custom block storage solution. Object storage is a 'fast enough' key/value system